# Windows 10 applying registry mouse settings

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, windows-registry, regedit

When I manually change any mouse settings in the registry using either regedit or PowerShell (MouseSpeed, MouseThreshold1, MouseThreshold2 MouseTrails, etc.) in the registry under

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse

Nothing applies until Windows is restarted. For example, I set MouseTrails to 6. This should turn MouseTrails setting to the second highest setting, but it isn't applied when I save the value. I restart the machine and then I have a trail following my cursor.

How can I apply these manual mouse registry changes without restarting my computer? Is it even possible? I'm not asking how to set these values via the Control Panel; I know that these settings work just fine through that.

For reference, I am running Windows 10 and have a Logitech G602. The Logitech software is installed in my computer but does not run on startup.

Comment: Did you try logoff/logon instead of a full restart?

Comment: Logoff/logon works fine because I'm editing under CURRENT_USER but I'm looking for a less intrusive method. Maybe a command in the command prompt?

Answer (score 3):

These settings can only be changed in a running session through the [`SystemParametersInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow) function. (That's how the mouse settings UI makes its changes.) If you already have a mechanism that writes your desired settings to the Registry, you can follow it up with this PowerShell script to read the Registry entries and apply them with `SystemParametersInfo`:

```
Add-Type @"
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class PInvoke {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam, int[] pvParam, int fWinIni);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam, System.IntPtr pvParam, int fWinIni);
}
"@

$mouse = Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Mouse'

# DoubleClickHeight -> SPI_SETDOUBLECLKHEIGHT
[PInvoke]::SystemParametersInfo(0x001E, $mouse.DoubleClickHeight, $null, 0)

# DoubleClickSpeed -> SPI_SETDOUBLECLICKTIME
[PInvoke]::SystemParametersInfo(0x0020, $mouse.DoubleClickSpeed, $null, 0)

# DoubleClickWidth -> SPI_SETDOUBLECLKWIDTH
[PInvoke]::SystemParametersInfo(0x001D, $mouse.DoubleClickWidth, $null, 0)

# MouseHoverHeight -> SPI_SETMOUSEHOVERHEIGHT
[PInvoke]::SystemParametersInfo(0x0065, $mouse.MouseHoverHeight, $null, 0)

# MouseHoverTime -> SPI_SETMOUSEHOVERTIME
[PInvoke]::SystemParametersInfo(0x0067, $mouse.MouseHoverTime, $null, 0)

# MouseHoverWidth -> SPI_SETMOUSEHOVERWIDTH
[PInvoke]::SystemParametersInfo(0x0063, $mouse.MouseHoverWidth, $null, 0)

# MouseSensitivity -> SPI_SETMOUSESPEED
[PInvoke]::SystemParametersInfo(0x0071, 0, [IntPtr][int]$mouse.MouseSensitivity, 0)

# MouseThreshold1, MouseThreshold2, MouseSpeed -> SPI_SETMOUSE
[PInvoke]::SystemParametersInfo(0x0004, 0, [int[]]($mouse.MouseThreshold1, $mouse.MouseThreshold2, $mouse.MouseSpeed), 0)

# MouseTrails -> SPI_SETMOUSETRAILS
[PInvoke]::SystemParametersInfo(0x005D, $mouse.MouseTrails, $null, 0)

# SnapToDefaultButton -> SPI_SETSNAPTODEFBUTTON
[PInvoke]::SystemParametersInfo(0x0060, $mouse.SnapToDefaultButton, $null, 0)

# SwapMouseButtons -> SPI_SETMOUSEBUTTONSWAP
[PInvoke]::SystemParametersInfo(0x0021, $mouse.SwapMouseButtons, $null, 2)
```

First it declares the `SystemParametersInfo` native function—twice with slightly different signatures, because the function is strangely inconsistent about how to pass the new setting. Then the script obtains the values of the `Mouse` Registry key. For each (except a few, mostly sound-related, that seem vestigial), the script calls the system parameters function with the appropriate action/setting code and input format [as listed in the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow#parameters). Each call outputs a 1 if successful. When updating the last setting, the `SPIF_SENDCHANGE` flag (2) is passed to notify other applications that changes have been made.

Since the script gets the data from the Registry, I chose not to have it redundantly update the Registry, but if you decide to adapt the script to set specific mouse settings instead of getting them from the Registry, apply `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE` to each `SystemParametersInfo` call by changing the last parameter from 0 to 1 or from 2 to 3.

Interestingly, the `ActiveWindowTracking` value is also vestigial—the setting is actually stored as part of the `UserPreferencesMask` in Desktop—but in case your existing script tried to use the vestigial value, this snippet will apply it for real:

```
# ActiveWindowTracking -> SPI_SETACTIVEWINDOWTRACKING
[PInvoke]::SystemParametersInfo(0x1001, 0, [IntPtr][int]$mouse.ActiveWindowTracking, 1)
```

To use the script, save it as a PS1 file, e.g. `regmouse.ps1`, then you can call it from a command prompt like so:

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file regmouse.ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

While registry need restart for sure, but try in this way may be it work.

Like you had done some changes in registry,  than call task manager by pressing CTRl+Alt+Del. Find the Explorer and Click on End Task. If shut down screen come - - > Click Cancel. Now Select File - -> New Task - -> Enter Explorer and Click OK.

In that you got New Explorer and with recent registry settings. Hope that helps.

Taken from this source: http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/246/

Comment: I should have mentioned in my original post, this method does not work.

Answer (score 0):

A great many registry settings are loaded at different points. Boot time, login, explorer launch et al.

I could be wrong, but I think the HKCU entries would require a sign-out, sign-in cycle at least.