# How can I prevent any user (not the admin) from changing mouse settings?

Tags: windows, windows-11, mouse, restrictions

In a school lab with PCs running Windows 11, I need to stop editing any of the mouse settings.

Comment: Well, not knowing what settings you are talking about, I would ask why? Just because it works for you, why do feel the need to force it on others? The usual one someone would want to change is swapping from right hand to left. Why would you force that on anyone?

Comment: @Bib Some students might mess with the sensitivity/swap left right as a prank to other students. It does make sense to restrict the settings unless you have people requiring ease of access settings.

Comment: @all It'ok to just prevent sensitivity/swap left right; do you know how to pls?

Comment: @user374324 so you want to deny a left handed person the ability to use the mouse properly? Why not just create a program which resets the settings?

Comment: I'm fairly sure the mouse settings are stored in the registry. You can set it to a default setting, and restore to that using startup script or group policy. That way, a user can mess with it, but after they log out, the settings will be reversed. Make sure you use computer startup script, not logon script as these regkeys are applied during logon. See also: https://superuser.com/questions/981554/windows-10-applying-registry-mouse-settings

Comment: Instead of stop editing, why not auto reset it on reboot?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the pro version of windows or Windows server, you can restrict settings via [Group Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/client-tools/manage-settings-app-with-group-policy):

> If your organization uses the Central Store for Group Policy
> management, to manage the policies, copy the ControlPanel.admx and
> ControlPanel.adml file to PolicyDefinitions folder.
>
> This policy is available for both User and Computer configurations.
>
> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Control Panel -> Settings Page Visibility.
>
> User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Control Panel -> Settings Page Visibility.

You can make a new configuration and hide the mouse settings (or any other settings, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/client-tools/manage-settings-app-with-group-policy) how which setting is named). To hide the mouse settings add the following rule:

`Hide:mousetouchpad`

Perhaps you also want to hide the ease of access settings as well:

`Hide:easeofaccess-mouse;easeofaccess-mousepointer`.

⚠ Do note that some people may rely on the ease of access settings.

Comment: This won't stop users from running *Control Panel > Mouse*.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse parameters are found in the registry at key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse`.

You have specified you wish to keep mouse sensitivity and
buttons swap.
These settings are controlled respectively by items
`MouseSensitivity` and `SwapMouseButtons`.

To save the current values of all mouse settings, run `regedit`,
but you can't simply position to the key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel`.
You need to position instead to `HKEY_USERS` and find the user's
key, which might look like
`HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2063358666-2461647202-2508659107-1001\Control Panel`.
Once found, right-click `Mouse` and select Export.

This will give you a `.reg` file containing the user's mouse settings.
However, applying it requires Administrator privileges, so you cannot
just run it from a standard user account.

I suggest  to create a task to run automatically on user login
in administrator mode. Follow the accepted answer in the post
[Schedule a task with admin privileges without a user prompt in windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/770420/schedule-a-task-with-admin-privileges-without-a-user-prompt-in-windows-7).

The scheduled task can run a `.bat` file that contains the command
[REG IMPORT \path\FileName.reg](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html).

This way, whenever that specific user account logs in,
its mouse settings are reset.
Other user accounts won't be affected.